# Going from dev to prod with .net Membership Provider

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I use SQLExpress on my dev machine. I just posted my application to a new prod server with SQL Server installed on it... I have restored my SQL DB in prod and i am successfully connecting to the DB with my connection string.

However, the membership provider seems to be failing to find my users in the DB.

Am i missing a step to configure or "activate" the membership provide on the prod server?

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong feeling it has to do with the `ApplicationName` property. I think you need to set the `ApplicationName` for Membership, Roles, and Profile providers.

I think this article talks about the problem you are facing...

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx