# Roles are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've manually published my asp.net website via ftp everything works fine( login,register etc..)
But roles are not working , for example : a page made only for admins can be accessed by normal users.

Here's my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnStrg" connectionString="provider details..etc.."
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyWebsiteTC">
        <providers>
          <add name="MyWebsiteTC"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
          applicationName="/"
          connectionStringName="MyConnStrg" />
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
      <membership defaultProvider="MyWebsiteTCMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="MyWebsiteTCMembershipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="MyConnStrg"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          applicationName="/"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
      </membership>

      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".KKDS"
          timeout="30"
          slidingExpiration="true"
          cookieless="UseCookies"
          defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
       />
      </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Admin files are in a folder with this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Client" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Roles were added for each user everything works fine but not the roles auth.
What can I do?

Comment: first of all you have an providers tag open twice

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
 <authorization>
    <allow roles="Client" />
    <deny users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```

because you want to allow users of role `Client` and deny **anyone else** (rather than deny users who are not logged in, as in your snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor Zychla made a good suggestion. If the site was working before you published it, I think the problem might have to do with the `ApplicationName`... I answered a question for someone else that deals with the `ApplicationName`. Look at this...

[Going from dev to prod with .net Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945705/going-from-dev-to-prod-with-net-membership-provider/11447246#11447246)